# Usable (mobile) user interface for adding quizzes and selecting a correct answer

Tags: mobile, mobile-application

I am creating an administration panel for an application and one of the needs is to manage quizzes in one page without any pop-ups.

The application should be usable both on mobile and desktop.

I had come up with a solution to show buttons next to each possible answer of a question and the green checkmark indicates the correct answer. When a user would hover one of the red crosses - they would turn into green checkmarks, which would indicate that the user has to click to make this answer the right one.

However hover doesn't work on mobile. What could be an alternative solution good for user experience that would also be usable on a phone?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using several buttons and components, it makes the UI too busy and less friendly.

Make a good use of *Radio Button* or *Checkbox* to signify choice and use styles to indicate correct or wrong choices, a typical user sees red and knows that's a wrong choice.

Here's a design to help you out.

**For Quiz Creator**

---

[image]

**For Person Attempting the Quiz(Quizee)**

---

*Before submission of Quiz.*

[image]

---

*After submission of Quiz.*

[image]

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough in the question, but I am trying to implement a UI for CREATING quizzes, not filling them.

Comment: Oh really, well, it still works, all the user(quiz creator) has to do is add options, that automatically appear with a radio button, then the selected option is the correct answer. However for delete purposes, a delete icon at the back of the radio button should be used, I'll edit my answer now.